# Generate private key encrypted with password using openssl

Tags: command-line, password, encryption, openssl

I'm using openssl to sign files, it works but I would like the private key file is encrypted with a password. These are the commands I'm using, I would like to know the equivalent commands using a password:

----- EDITED -----

I put here the updated commands with password:

```
- Use the following command to generate your private key using the RSA algorithm:

$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:foobar -out private.key 2048


- Use the following command to extract your public key:

$ openssl rsa -in private.key -passin pass:foobar -pubout -out public.key


- Use the following command to sign the file:

$ openssl dgst -sha512 -sign private.key -passin pass:foobar -out signature.bin file.txt


- To verify the signature:

$ openssl dgst -sha512 -verify public.key -signature signature.bin file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the "passout" flag, for the "foobar" password it would be: `-passout pass:foobar`

In your first example it become `openssl genrsa -passout pass:foobar -out private.key 2048`

You can also use: `openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048`
This will ask you to enter a passphrase.

You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-an-openssl-key-using-a-passphrase-from-the-command-line

Comment: If I use the password in the first command, still can use the other commands without password to generate public key, sign the file and check the signature and they work, so something is missing here

Comment: You can try with -aes256 at the begining so your first command would be openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048

Comment: It works now, I will update my question so others can use it

Comment: Only the second command `openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048` triggers a passphrase prompt.

Comment: When I create using `openssl genrsa -passout pass:foobar -out private.key 2048` I can decrypt without using password foobar. Why is this?

Comment: HEADS-UP!!! The command `openssl genrsa -passout pass:foobar -out private.key 2048` DOES NOT result in an encrypted key.  View the resulting content.  See the header `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` , this should be `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` instead.